# Quadruple nested quotations in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using **curl** to get items from a GraphQL API. I need to send the item name to get the id of it as a response. This works fine when the name is just one word, but I can't seem to make it work when it contains blank spaces.

```
itemName="Variable with blank spaces"
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '$itemName'\") {results {id}}"}'
```

How can I escape the $itemName in the query above

Comment: Can you post the data you want to send after text gets unquoted? You want to send `{"query": "(getItems(jql: \" ~ 'Variable with blank spaces'\")"}` ? Ie. the `'` should be inside `"`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated it, it's just what I expect to get as a result, the id of the item. And the ```'``` inside the ```"``` is a requirement in the documentation. Is there a way to escape the variable name once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include a `'` in a `'`-delimited string or script in any shell. No amount of attempted escaping will make it work. Period. So to get a `'` to appear in a command-line you need to break out of the enclosing `'`s, provide a `'`, then get back into it to continue with the rest of the `'`-delimited string/command.

The usual syntax to get a `'` into a string is to use `'\''` wherever a `'` is needed, eg.:

```
str='foo'\''bar'
```

sets the variable `str` to `foo'bar`.

So, with your command line you'd use the following to get `'`s:

```
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '\''$itemName'\''\") {results {id}}"}'
```

but you additionally need to let the shell expand `$itemName` which you ALSO need to break out of the `'`s for and also double-quote while back in the shell to avoid globbing and expansion (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). You could write that as:

```
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '\'''"$itemName"''\''\") {results {id}}"}'
```

but we're getting a `'`-pileup getting immediately in/out of the shell twice there that's not necessary - just stay in shell and expand the variable while you're there. So you can reduce it to:

```
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '\'"$itemName"\''\") {results {id}}"}'
```

or, since `\'` is the same as `"'"`:

```
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '"'$itemName'"'\") {results {id}}"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `'`. So end quoting `'` escape single `\'` then add the item `"$itemName"` then add single quote `\'` and re-start single quoting `'`.

```
curl -X POST -data '{"query": "{getItems(jql: \"text ~ '\'"$itemName"\''\") {results {id}}"}'
```

or use `"`:

```
curl -X POST -data "{\"query\": \"{getItems(jql: \\\"text ~ '$itemName'\\\") {results {id}}\"}"
```